# Hide div in sidebar depending on number of WooCommerce products

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to hide a div in the left sidebar depending on how many WooCommerce products are displayed?

Let's say the div in the sidebar is called 'last-img' and the number of products would have to be > 9 to display the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that would be using js, counting your elements using `getElementsByClassName`:

```
var numberOfElements = document.getElementsByClassName('products').length;
```

Then :

```
if (numberOfElements > 9) {
document.getElementById('last-img').style.display = 'block';
} else {
document.getElementById('last-img').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Thank you @stacks for the quick response. I am super new to js. Do I put it all together in a script or put the first line in a script and the last part in a new script? What file would I put this in. Would I put this in archive-product.php or in the header file?

Comment: @user2373595 Just put this inside `<script>` tags inside of your html file. Correct way to implement this would be before the closing `<body>` tag so that your loading does not get slowed down but with this amount of code it's not an issue. Also don't hesitate to mark this as answer!

Comment: I have placed the code:
`<script>
var numberOfElements = document.getElementsByClassName('products').length;
if (numberOfElements > 9) {
document.getElementById('last-img').style.display = 'block';
} else {
document.getElementById('last-img').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>`
All over my archive-product.php to try and get it to work.
I am getting this message: 
null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('last-img').style').
"last-img" is the div I use inside a custom HTML widget. I also tried to put the script in the widget with no luck.

Comment: That is strange that it does not work with the widget. Then the id must not be 'last-img'. You need to figure out what exactly is the id of the div you want to hide or show. Anyways I answered to your question which is how to hide/show a div inside a HTML page depending on the number of a given elements.

Comment: Oh my fault. I was using div class and not id. So I fixed that part but now it is hiding the div when the number is more and less then 9

Comment: I found it. I had to use 'product-type-external' instead of 'products'. Works perfect. Thanks you!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm always very happy to help :) Happy Easter!

Comment: When filtering down to say 1 product the 'last-img' still displays. Is it an easy fix to make it work for filtering or does the webpage have to load for this js to work?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what is happening right now? You could encapsulate the `else if` statement I gave you inside a function and call it when `window.onload` and also when filtering ?

Comment: For instance say I have 20 products so then the 'last-img' displays. Now I filter the color attribute "black" and now only 5 products display (the webpage does not reload) but 'last-img' still displays even though there are less than 9 products. Is that fixable?

Comment: Yes, you have to find out the filtering function that updates your products display, and inside of it call the same `else if` statement I gave you. You can encapsulate this `else if` statement in a function and call it when your page loads with `window.onload` and then in your filtering function to make your code clearer.

Comment: Awesome! I was able to find the right spot to put it. Thanks again for putting up with me.

Comment: Nice, i'm glad that it works now, you're welcome :)